# .htaccess forward different Domains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 Domains which i want to forward.

Example

1. http://www.domain.com
2. http://doma.in

I want to forward it like this

http://domain.com ---> redirects to http://www.domain.com

http://www.domain.com ---> redirection not required

http://subdomain.domain.com ---> redirection not required

http://www.doma.in ---> redirect to http://doma.in

This Condition is doing all until the shorted Domain http://doma.in

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

How can i solve to allow the last Domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.doma\.in$
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://doma.in/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i get an Error
--
The script could not be executed correctly.
Common causes might be that the file was uploaded in a non-ASCII format or the path to the interpreter (e.g.: #!/usr/bin/perl) is missing or set incorrectly. But it is in ASCII Mode uploaded

Comment: "The **script** could not be executed correctly" So the error has nothing to do with the rules. Check your script.